# Polymerscript not working

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

i have another `polymer` problem, i don't know how to solve it.
This script does not work:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
</head>
<body>

    <home></home>

</body>
</html>
```

elements.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="home/home.html">
```

home.html

```
<dom-module id="home">

<template>
    <style>
    </style>

    Hello World
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "home"
    });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

Sorry I'm new at `polymer`, thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stuipid fault of me, it is not allowed to define elements without a `-`.

e.g. `home` --> `home-main`